# Ruby: Dynamically build member name of a struct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two questions.

1) I need to create a dynamic structure, whose members are driven through an array.
For ex:

```
    members = [:a, :b]
    Config  = Struct.new(members) #=> Struct.new(:a, :b)
    FlatConfig = Struct.new(members) #=> Struct.new(:a, :b)
    config = Config.new()
    flat = FlatConfig.new()
```

After some days, If I need to add another member to these struct, then all I need to do is add a member in that members array (memebers = [:a, :b, :c]) and I don't need to tough the code further. Thus I am asking this. How to achieve this?

2) Now I need to build the values of flat Struct members by means of doing some manipulation on config struct member values. 
For eg:

```
    config.each{|configMember|
      result = configMember.collect{|c| someArray.collect{|s| s + '--' + y}}
      flat[":#{cofigMember}"] = result #=> Intent is to store result in same member as iterated through  config struct.
    }
```

How to achieve (1) and (2)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your 1), use the splat operator:

```
Struct.new(*members)
```

I don't really understand your second question. Is "how can I access the same variable in two configs"?

```
config.members.each { |key|
  configMember = config[key]
  # do something
  flat[key] = result
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your update. In (2), config and flat structs have different member names (keys). Flat config has same member names as config struct, but with prefix "flat_". Now how to store result to flat struct?

Comment: `flat[:"flat_#{key}"] = result`